# How can I skip steps and move to the last step from the first step itself in spring batch?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job which needs to be executed only in case if certain condition is met. Knew about the job decider using **JobExecutionDecider**. However, I can't use it as the starting step as *start() always requires a Step as parameter*.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional job flow is a basic functionality of Spring Batch. It is well documented. Please try first to read the docu linked bellow. If you will have any issues please post a specific question.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-conditional-flow

Comment: This is to handle errors? I want to skip the entire job based on the condition. As per my understanding, I will be able to use Flow as it can be passed to the start()